# Swap image classes on click of an a tag. jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover, addclass, removeclass

I am working with jQuery and attempting to swap an image Style on click. I am using .tabs for a multi-page form and would like to call an event to swap out an image class when that page is clicked. Kind of like A form process complete status. Like breadcrumbs type. My code is as follows. Any help towards the right direction would be very much appreciated. -Thanks

JS:

```
$(function () {
        $("#nav-ul li a").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('img#no-1').removeClass("nav-number");
            $(this).children('img').addClass("nav-number-active")
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="nav-Container">
        <ul id="nav-ul">
            <li>
                <a href="#page-1" class="nav-a-link">General Information
                <img src="images/no-images/img-no-1.png" id="no-1" class="nav-number" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#page-2" class="nav-a-link">Setpoints
                <img src="images/no-images/img-no-2.png" id="no-2" class="nav-number" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#page-3">Call Flow Structure
                <img src="images/no-images/img-no-3.png" id="no-3" class="nav-number" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#page-4">Summary
                <img src="images/no-images/img-no-4.png" id="no-4" class="nav-number" />
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

StyleSheet:

```
.nav-number{
    margin:0px;
    float:right;
    padding:10px 0px 0px 13px;
    opacity:0.4;
    border:0px;
}
.nav-number-active{
    margin:0px;
    float:right;
    padding:10px 0px 0px 13px;
    border:0px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YSESD/2/

Answer (score 0):

When calling addClass or removeClass, don't use a '.'. Call it by name.

```
 $("#nav-ul li").delegate("a", "click", function () {
         $(this).children("a").addClass("nav-number")
             .siblings().removeClass("nav-number-active");
             return false;
     });
```

Also, not sure why you're using `$(this).children("a")` inside an event handler for `a`. shouldn't it just be `$(this).find('img').addClass(....`?

Also, better to remove the active class first, then add it to the one you want:

```
 $("#nav-ul li").delegate("a", "click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a.nav-number-active').removeClass("nav-number-active");
    $(this).addClass("nav-number-active")
 });
```

Comment: thanks for the heads up.   now I'm getting an error in IE: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'prentDefault' / No functionality in Firefox.

Comment: Sorry, typo. preventDefault(); I'll fix.

Comment: Right on.   but... Still no luck.  I'm going to try a simple code on jsf, see what I'm doing wrong here.   Thanks

Comment: I just updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YSESD/3/. Your delegate method was looking inside itself. And also 'A' != 'a'

Comment: The strangest thing, yours still wouldn't work.   I shut down the computer and crashed out.  This morning checked out your changes on fiddle again and they worked.  I applied the following to code and it functions.   I used .children() to prevent applying any oddities to the img class swap-out.   Seems to work just fine.  I have a little tweaking to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var navs = $('#nav-ul a');
    navs.on('click', function () {    
       navs.removeClass('active');         
        $(this).addClass('active');
   });
```

Comment: Is the markup available on the page when the function is called? You may check in the browser console, whether you can get navs.length > 0 ? something like alert(navs.length) or console.log(navs.length) will indicate whether you have targeted the elements correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected the names in the script.  Setup to remove class first then add.  Also some strange bug in the system was preventing results.  I did a simple computer restart and that did the trick.  Not sure what the cause but suspect cache.?

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this

```
$(function () {
    $("#nav-ul li a").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find("img").removeClass("nav-number").addClass("nav-number-active");
    });
});
```

alternatively you could use toggleClass to make it cleaner, but if you click it again it would revert back to the original class.

```
$(function () {
    $("#nav-ul li a").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find("img").toggleClass("nav-number nav-number-active");
    });
});
```